# ignite upgrade from 2.7 to 2.11 , error occurred during startup

Tags: ignite

I use ansible install ignite, just replace artiface zip. The error log for the startup script is as follows, it's strange ClassNotFoundException:ZkDiscoveryNodeFailEventData( which occur in 2.7 version).

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.internal.ZkDiscoveryNodeFailEventData
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:9064)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:9002)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.resolveClass(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:59)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2568)
        at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2551)
        at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2508)
        at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(TreeMap.java:2454)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:124)
        ... 11 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
tail: /opt/rdx/log/ignite/ignite_console.out: file truncated
```

Comment: Check which modules are present in $WORK_DIR/libs folder. Maybe ignite-zookeeper module still enabled for one of your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem , just change zkRootPath from `/apacheIgnite` to `/otherPath`, or connect zookeeper shell and `rmr /apacheIgnite`

```xml
<property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="zkConnectionString" value="ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181"/>
            <property name="zkRootPath" value="/apacheIgnite"/>
            <property name="sessionTimeout" value="400000"/>
        </bean>
 </property>
```

besides, you need to delete the data for the paths in the following properties

```xml
<property name="storagePath" value="/xxx/persistent" />
<property name="walPath" value="/xxx/wal_store"/>
<property name="walArchivePath" value="/xxx/wal_archive"/>
```